# How to turn an image's file path into the actual image?

Tags: php, mysql, html, filepath

I've saved a user's respective picture in a folder named 'profileportraits'. So when a user uploads their picture, it is saved into that folder. Furthermore, I also save the 'portrait path', i.e. the location/name of the photo onto a MySQL database for user data. My question is: I am able to echo the Portrait Path, where the user's portrait is stored onto the page. But how will I display the **actual** photo onto the page? I.e. how can I turn the file path into the actual picture? Will I have to match the path that I retrieved from MySQL to the directory? or something else? Below is a bit of code.

```
{
echo $row['PortraitPath'];
}
```

With the code above, I am able to echo the actual path, which is: **profileportraits/DSC00310.JPG**. I simply want to turn this path of the picture, into the actual picture. Thank you.

Comment: I hope you're not storing those images with user-provided filenames. Consider what happens if two different users both upload 'DSC00310.JPG' at different times. You may want to assign unique names to each uploaded file, like the db record's auto_increment primary key value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['PortraitPath']; ?>" />
```

or

```
<?php
echo "<img src=\"{$row['PortraitPath']}\" />";
?>
```

Comment: Don't forget the ALT attribute. ;) Just a thought was that _PortraitPath_ was perhaps the server-side path which didn't quite match the appropriate client side URL? If not then great, otherwise you'll need to convert it to a URL.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use the path as the source of an image tag:

```
echo "<img src=\"{$row['PortraitPath']}\" />"
```